# keras LSTM get hidden-state (converting sentece-sequence to document context vectors)

Tags: python, keras, lstm, embedding, bert-language-model

Im trying to create document context vectors from sentence-vectors via LSTM using keras (so each document consist of a sequence of sentence vectors).

My goal is to replicate the following blog post using keras: https://andriymulyar.com/blog/bert-document-classification

I have a (toy-)tensor, that looks like this: `X = np.array(features).reshape(5, 200, 768)` So 5 documents with each having a 200 sequence of sentence vectors - each sentence vector having 768 features.

So to get an embedding from my sentence vectors, I encoded my documents as one-hot-vectors to learn an LSTM:

```
y = [1,2,3,4,5] # 5 documents in toy-tensor
y = np.array(y)
yy = to_categorical(y)
yy = yy[0:5,1:6]
```

Until now, my code looks like this

```
inputs1=Input(shape=(200,768))
lstm1, states_h, states_c =LSTM(5,dropout=0.3,recurrent_dropout=0.2, return_state=True)(inputs1)
model1=Model(inputs1,lstm1)
model1.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer='rmsprop',metrics=['acc']) 
model1.summary()
model1.fit(x=X,y=yy,batch_size=100,epochs=10,verbose=1,shuffle=True,validation_split=0.2)
```

**When I print `states_h` I get a tensor of shape=(?,5) and I dont really know how to access the vectors inside the tensor, which should represent my documents.**

```
print(states_h)
Tensor("lstm_51/while/Exit_3:0", shape=(?, 5), dtype=float32)
```

Or am I doing something wrong? To my understanding there should be 5 document vectors e.g. `doc1=[...] ; ...; doc5=[...]` so that I can reuse the document vectors for a classification task.

Comment: Which TF version are you using? And are you using `keras` or `tf.keras`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, printing a tensor shows exactly this: it's a tensor, it has that shape and that type.

If you want to see data, you need to feed data.
States are not weights, they are not persistent, they only exist with input data, just as any other model output.

You should create a model that outputs this information (yours doesn't) in order to grab it. You can have two models:

```
#this is the model you compile and train - exactly as you are already doing
training_model = Model(inputs1,lstm1)     

#this is just for getting the states, nothing else, don't compile, don't train
state_getting_model = Model(inputs1, [lstm1, states_h, states_c])
```

(Don't worry, these two models will share the same weights and be updated together, even if you only train the `training_model`)

Now you can:

**With eager mode off (and probably "on" too):**

```
lstm_out, states_h_out, states_c_out = state_getting_model.predict(X)
print(states_h_out)
print(states_c_out)
```

**With eager mode on:**

```
lstm_out, states_h_out, states_c_out = state_getting_model(X)
print(states_h_out.numpy())
print(states_c_out.numpy())
```

Comment: Ok, Im still too new to keras to fully understand: I do set up my ```inputs1``` and ```lstm1, states_h, states_c``` as shown above and then use both ```training_model``` and ```state_getting_model``` to set up my ```Model()```? Then I run ```training_model.compile()``` and ```.fit()``` to train my model and it will also train the ```state_getting_model```? That cant be right..I do get an Error if I run ```.compile()``` and ```fit()``` on the state_getting_model ```Error when checking model target: the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected```

Comment: @Felix , You don't have to train or compile the `state_getting_model`. You have to train and compile the `training_model` only.

Comment: `training_model` and `state_getting_model` are two different models, but they share all the layers and weights. `training_model` outputs only the data you want to train. `state_getting_model` outputs the data and the states.

Comment: How is it possible that the ```state_getting_model ``` is sharing the same weights even when its not compiled and fit to the data? Is it because Keras ```Model()``` runs iteratively and is updated so ```Model()``` itself adjust to the input / output data? Hmm.. I probably have to dive deeper into keras :-/

Comment: Because it uses exactly the same layers. While `training_model` goes from the input tensor `inputs1`, passes through all the layers until the output tensor `lstm1`; the model `state_getting_model` follows almost exactly the same path (and naturally the same layers), from the input tensor `inputs1` also until the output tensor `lstm1`, but including the two additional output tensors `states_h` and `states_c` (which come out from the same layer that the output tensor `lstm1` comes). So, all you did was to create two models (or functions) that use the exact same layers.

Answer (score 1):

### TF 1.x with `tf.keras` (Tested with TF 1.15)

Keras does operations using symbolic tensors. Therefore, `print(states_h)` won't give you anything unless you pass data to the placeholders `states_h` depends on (in this case `inputs1`). You can do that as follows.

```
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K

inputs1=Input(shape=(200,768))
lstm1, states_h, states_c =LSTM(5,dropout=0.3,recurrent_dropout=0.2, return_state=True)(inputs1)
model1=Model(inputs1,lstm1)
model1.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer='rmsprop',metrics=['acc']) 
model1.summary()
model1.fit(x=X,y=yy,batch_size=100,epochs=10,verbose=1,shuffle=True,validation_split=0.2)

sess = K.get_session()
out = sess.run(states_h, feed_dict={inputs1:X})
```

Then `out` will be `(batch_size, 5)` sized output.

### TF 2.x with `tf.keras`

The above code won't work as it is. And I still haven't found how to get this to work with TF 2.0 (even though TF 2.0 will still produce a placeholder according to [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Input?version=stable)). I will edit my answer when I find how to fix this for TF 2.x.

Comment: Im really sorry, but I dont understand how to include the ```get_session()``` in my code.. if I run ```sess.run(...)``` I do get a ```FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value lstm_57/bias...```  could you explain a bit further?

Comment: @Felix In order to use sess.run(...) in this case, you first need to have run `model.compile()` and `model.fit()`. Did you try to run without those? Because that's one scenarios where you'd get the above error.

Comment: Hm it seems like a path error ```FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value lstm_59/kernel
  [[node lstm_59/kernel/read (defined at C:\Users\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py:402) ]]``` and I still get it when I run all the above.. I think I have to check my paths